# Visual basic empty text box throws exception

Tags: vb.net

The code below is a program to calculate the BMI using text boxes. I am having an issue however that when I clear one of the text boxes it will throw an exception and freeze the program. I was wondering if anyone had an answer on how to prevent this. I already tried setting my variables to 0 and 1 to see if that was the issue but it does not appear to be.

```
Private Sub tboxWeight_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tboxWeight.TextChanged
    Weight = 0
    Weight = Convert.ToInt64(tboxWeight.Text)
End Sub

Private Sub tboxHFeet_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tboxHFeet.TextChanged
    Height_feet = 0
    Height_feet = Convert.ToInt64(tboxHFeet.Text)
    Get_BMI(1)
End Sub

Private Sub tboxHInch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tboxHInch.TextChanged
    Height_Inches = 0
    Height_Inches = Convert.ToInt64(tboxHInch.Text)
    Get_BMI(1)
End Sub



Private Sub tboxAge_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles tboxAge.TextChanged
    Age = Convert.ToDouble(tboxAge.Text)

End Sub

Function Get_BMI(ByVal j As Integer) As Double
    BMI = (Weight / (Height_Inches + (Height_feet * 12) ^ 2) * 703)
    tboxBMI.Text = Convert.ToString(BMI)
    Exit Function
End function
```

Comment: See the *remarks* section of [MSDN on Convert.ToXxxx(string)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zahhahw(v=vs.110).aspx) - use `TryParse` instead, if you don't want to handle an exception when the conversion fails.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you set a textbox into an integer field, so when the textbox is empty it will throw exception because the textbox doesn't contain a number.
Try using If else statement for each textboxes. 
`String.IsNullOrEmpty` function will be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Good/Best practice says, you need to validate the data before performing calculation i.e. Get_BMI(). Below code snippet will help you.

```
Dim textBoxValue As String
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(textBoxValue) Then
    If IsNumeric(textBoxValue) Then

    End If
End If
```

Comment: How can it be numeric if it's null or empty? I think you meant `Not`...

Comment: @Zaggler is correct. I made the correction in if Condition.

Comment: `IsNumeric()` can be pretty awful, too. The `TryParse()` functions are a much better option.